# Angular 4 Event Delegation

Tags: angular, typescript, event-delegation

I am required to detect a click event on a pseudo-element (::after) which holds an icon in CSS. This pseudo-element is a sibling of a `<select>` HTML Element and will open/toggle/display all the `<option>` inside that `<select>`.

I am propagating the click event to the parent element and triggering the focus event on the `<select>` using `this.selectDropdown.nativeElement.focus();`.

PS: `selectDropdown` of type ElementRef is decorated with `@ViewChild('selectDropdown')` and placed in the `<select #selectDropdown>`.

Do you have any idea, guys?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Could you please create a minimal reproducible example (plunker/jsfiddle)?

Comment: It's a little hacky and I dont know if you can use in your case but using rxjs fromEvent seems to work

Comment: The event is captured but the <select> does not unfold. I will provide a jsfiddle